# C++ Thread works fine long time but then I'm getting abort error

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I have built up a procedural terrain creator using voxels. The terrain is divived in chunks, those chunks are created in a seperate, detached thread. Since I did this, there is no lag anymore because they get built in background. Everything works fine for about 2000 chunks (32*32*64), but then i get an "abort() has been called" error. The debug information looks just fine.

Enough words, here is some code:

In the Manager-constructor the Thread is initialized:

```
try{
        m_creatorThread1 = std::thread(&ChunkManager::CreateChunk, this);
        m_creatorThread1.detach();
    }
    catch (...){
        m_work = false;
        m_creatorThread1.join();
        throw;
    }
```

This is the function the thread executes:

```
void ChunkManager::CreateChunk(){
    while (m_work){ 
        if (!m_buildQ.empty()){
            Position tmp = m_buildQ.back();
            m_buildQ.pop_back();
            Chunk* ctmp = new Chunk(this->m_terrain, tmp);
            m_mutex.lock();
            m_chunks.push_back(ctmp);
            m_mutex.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

the function that feeds the m_buildQ:

```
void ChunkManager::GenerateChunks(Position position){
        for (int i = position.x - CHUNK_PRLD_X; i < position.x + CHUNK_PRLD_X; i++){
            for (int j = position.z - CHUNK_PRLD_Z; j < position.z + CHUNK_PRLD_Z; j++){
                Position chunkPos;
                chunkPos.x = i *CHUNK_SIZE; chunkPos.z = j *CHUNK_SIZE;     
                if (!IsUsed(chunkPos)){
                    m_used.push_back(chunkPos);
                    m_buildQ.push_back(chunkPos);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and finally the function that renders the chunks:

```
void ChunkManager::Render(){
    m_mutex.lock();
    for (vector<Chunk*>::iterator it = m_chunks.begin(); it != m_chunks.end(); ++it){
        if (m_Frustum->CheckSphere((*it)->getPosition().x +CHUNK_SIZE/2, CHUNK_HEIGHT / 2, (*it)->getPosition().z + CHUNK_SIZE/2, CHUNK_SIZE*1.3f)){
            if ((*it)->hasGraphics())
                (*it)->Render();
            else{
                (*it)->InitializeGraphics(OpenGL);
            }
        }
    }
    m_mutex.unlock();
}
```

In short: Every frame there is a check if new chunks need to be loaded, if so, GenerateChunks feeds the m_buildQ vector with positions of chunks that got to be loaded. The thread runs in background and creates new chunks if something is in the buildQ. because of openGL-reasons, the VAO and VBO dont get initialized in the thread but in the renderer if needed.

As I said, everything works fine until I've spent some time in the application and thousands of chunks were created. Can anyone find the mistake?

Here some things of the debug:

```
m_chunks: size= 1392
it-ptr: points on valid chunk
thread: hnd:0x00000264 id: 0
```

if someone needs more debug information just tell me.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't e.g. running out of memory?

Comment: I agree with Daniel. It could be from running out of memory. Also, what is the type of m_buildQ? Unless it is a lock-free stack, that could be your problem. How often is Render being called?

Comment: Joining a detached thread is impossible, which is already one bug in your code.

Comment: A suggestion that may help: Look into the concepts of having a batch class along with a batch manager! They work nicely by minimizing the amount of render calls being sent from the CPU to the GPU reducing cycles. Also in your Batch Manager class you can have a render queue that will wait until your Batches are filled reducing the number of times your batch manager will empty its buckets. This will also help to limit the amount of ram you are using!

Comment: I dont think It runs out of memory.  Ressource Manager sais the exe uses lass than 500 MB for those chunks. M_buildQ is a vector storing porsitions which is a struct of float x,z. Render is called every frame. Even if joining a detached thread is impossible,  It helped getting rid of an exception when calling the destructor of the class.  I will try this batch thing this evening,  thanks.

Comment: I just checked again. I may have been mistaken with the RAM. Actually he stops at 1,89 GB used RAM. I will try and store the chunk data in a file or database and see if the problem is getting solved.